# Control two prototype cells of a single table view using segmented control of another view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two view controllers namely "userTableViewController" and "InsertRecordViewController". And in the InsertRecordViewController i have a segmented control which is meant to control the two prototype cells "cell1" and "cell2" of the userTableViewController.

Any idea guys??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: not able think of a way to access the prototype cells of "userTableViewController" into my "InsertRecordViewController"

Comment: you need to change datasource

Comment: how do i do that?? i'm new to this

Comment: You need to Make condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath method depending on your requirement  prepare the cells and return it .

Comment: when the user clicks on a segmented control tab i want to display a specific prototype cell in the userTableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

First you add two customTableViewCell.

Then import in your viewController class.\

Then add this following code.It will help full to you.[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell;

    AnotherTableViewCell *cell1;

    if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

        cell =[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      }else{


         cell1 =[[AnotherTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

     if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

        return cell;

    }else{

        return cell1;

  }

}
```